# Calling python from R package whitespace error

Tags: python, r

I have downloaded the R package [divo](http://cran/web/packages/divo/index.html).  I consistently get the error:

> divo environment check: Failed.

Solutions:

1. Check write permissions for working directory,
2. Check if dependences are installed and configured correctly.

   > Warning message: running command 'python C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/divo/DivO_EnvCheck.py' had status 2

I believe the error is that the command line call to python:

```
python C:/Program Files...
```

contains a space.  Manually, I can enclose the path in quotes and run `DivO_EnvCheck.py`, but I need to get the package to run correctly so I can access a function.

Can anyone suggest a workaround other than to change the location of R to somewhere without a space in the parent directory?  Is it possible to edit the package to include quotes in the call to python?

Comment: What do  you mean by "get the package to run correctly so I can access a function"?

Comment: System requirements for `divo`: Python (>=2.76), NumPy. Make sure you have those.

Comment: I have contacted the author of Devo to report this as a bug. Hopefully the fix will be included in a future update.